# how to download ubuntu 14.10 onto a passport usb drive

Tags: 14.04

I go to site, select desktop version, and select download  a file is downloaded but it is not runnable.  It is a .iso file

I copied it to the passport drive

I am using windows 8.1, wish to down load ubuntu as above, and then use virtual box

I have 14.04 running on a old system

Comment: Do you want to install ubuntu on virtual box guest or to a full PC?

Comment: I plan to install a bootable version of 14.04 onto the passport drive then install vmbox later

Comment: when i download Unetbootin, how do i "Run Executable"? - second step below.Is it a file? what name?  Location

Comment: I added an edit in the answer.

Comment: I selected windows and got to download screen.  I have a WD Passport 1TB USB drive.  Windows recognizes it, I formatted it, I select USB drive, but cannot enter D: in drive window

Comment: The WD Passport 1TB is not a usb drive. it is an external Hard disk

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow the instructions in ubuntu site described [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows).
These instructions require installation of "Universal USB installer". Afterwards, you can create the bootable USB drive.

Alternatively you can use [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) which does not require installation to your Windows 8.1 system. Just

- Download Unetbootin
- Run Executable
- Browse to ISO file
- Select USB drive
- Press OK

EDIT: When clicking the [link](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/unetbootin-windows-latest.exe) you download the USB installer executable. After downloading just double click the executable.